# Retrieving the COM class factory for component 80040154 Class not registered - DLL is definitely in registry and app is using x86

Tags: c#, com

I'm trying to integrate a Brother QL-700 label printer into a C# application that I'm writing. I've created a console application to test the printer with and added the following code (taken from the SDK on the Brother website):

```
class Program
{
    private const string TEMPLATE_DIRECTORY = @"c:\program files\brother bpac3 sdk\templates\";
    private const string TEMPLATE_FRAME = @"NamePlate2.LBX";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string templatePath = TEMPLATE_DIRECTORY;
        templatePath += TEMPLATE_FRAME;

        IDocument doc = new bpac.Document();

        if (doc.Open(templatePath) != false)
        {
            doc.GetObject("objCompany").Text = "Company";
            doc.GetObject("objName").Text = "Your name here...";

            doc.StartPrint("", PrintOptionConstants.bpoDefault);
            doc.PrintOut(1, PrintOptionConstants.bpoDefault);
            doc.EndPrint();
            doc.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Open() error: " + doc.ErrorCode);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }



    }
}
```

The application stops on the line where I create a new instance of bpac.Document and it throws the following error message:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {B940C105-7F01-46FE-BF41-E040B9BDA83D} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).'

There are several other posts on Stack Overflow about this issue and I have tried some of the commonly suggested fixes:

1. The DLL in question is definitely in the Windows registry
2. I have changed the application architecture on the console application to x86

I'm still unable to make any progress. Does anyone else have any other ideas?

Comment: Suggest you try making it x64--assuming you are on a 64-bit OS like most people are these days. If you don't make it x64, it generally defaults to an x86 compatible mode in my experience. So, you making it x86 explicitly is just doing what it probably was already doing. Also, you are looking for template in sub-directory of "c:\program files" and not "c:\program files (x86)". IOW, you are getting the template from the x64 directory. So, for those reasons, I'd try making it as x64.

Comment: amazingly this worked for me. No idea why